# Backbone.js - delete views

Tags: backbone.js

This is my second day trying to use backbone and im completely lost. I am following this tutorial -   http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/build-a-contacts-manager-using-backbone-js-part-3/

What I have done is loaded a contacts list and rendered it to the screen, but if you look at my render1 function - this takes a form input and appends it to my template. The problem is that I can't delete these items after they are created - the others can be deleted. help please?

```
      var ContactView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "contacts",
    className: "contact-container",
    template: $("#contactTemplate").html(),

    initialize: function(){
        this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
        this.model.on('add',    this.render1, this);
        this.model.on('destroy', this.remove, this);
    },

    events: {
        'click .deleteUser': 'delete'
    },

    test: function () {
        alert("here");
    },

    delete: function () {
        this.model.destroy();
    },

    render: function () {
        console.log(this);
        var tmpl = _.template(this.template);
        $(this.el).html(tmpl(this.model.toJSON()));
        temp = tmpl(this.model.toJSON());
        console.log(temp);
        return this;
    },
    render1: function () {
        console.log(this);
        var tmpl = _.template(this.template);
        temp = tmpl(this.model.toJSON());
        temp='<contacts class="contact-container">'+temp+'</contacts>';
        console.log(temp);
        $("#contacts").append(temp);
        $(this.el).html(tmpl(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});

var AddPerson = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#addPerson"),
    // el: $("form/"),

    events: {
        'click': 'submit',
        'submit': 'submit'
    },

    submit: function(e) {
        // alert("here");
        e.preventDefault();
        this.collection = new Directory();
        // var data = (contacts[0]);
        var contact = new Contact(contacts[0]);
        var contactView = new ContactView({model: contact});
        this.collection.add(contact);
        this.collection.add(contactView);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

seasick, there are quite a few issues in this code.

```
var contact = new Contact(contacts[0]);
var contactView = new ContactView({model: contact});
this.collection.add(contact);
this.collection.add(contactView);
```

Contact is a Backbone.Model but ContactView is a Backbone.View. Yet, you are adding both to the this.collection (which I assume is a Backbone.Collection of Contact?). See the problem here? In Backbone, there is no such concept of a 'collection of views'. You just get one concept: views, that are tied to a model.

So, here, you create a Contact and you add it to the Collection. That is all! It takes care of the Model part. The rendering part needs to be handled with events and renders.

When you add a model to a collection (this.collection.add(contact)), the collection will trigger a 'add' event, that you can hook to with a .on to create a new ContactView and append it to the DOM somewhere.

So when you write this...

```
this.model.on('add',    this.render1, this);
```

You are actually saying 'When the Contact model triggers an add event, run render1', which isn't what you want, what you probably want is a collection.on('add', ...). The model will never trigger an add event (well, you could make it trigger one, but it wouldn't be an expected behavior!), the add/remove events are at the collection level.

In other words, you are missing some binding on the collection in your AddPerson view to 'react' to adding a new Contact to the collection. The code of the function bound to the add event should probably look a bit like:

```
onAdd: function(newContact){
  var newContactView = new ContactView({model: newContact});
  $("#contacts").append(newContactView.render().el);
}
```

There are other issues in your code, but I guess an outline of the steps to take would be like:

1. Remove the binding to add in ContactView: ContactView is only concerned with one contact, not how to manage multiple contacts. This is probably why you are having issues with only some (the first one?) of the contacts 'working'
2. Move that logic to the AddContact view which seems to be more concerned with the Collection of contacts. Use the collection 'add' event to create new ContactView and append them to the DOM

Hope this helps!

Comment: To be picky, "You just get one concept: views, that are tied to a model." isn't quite true, views also have native support for `this.collection` as well as `this.model`.

Comment: Ah! Right :) You can indeed pass either a collection, a model or both to the View constructor and it'll be merged in the properties (making it available in this without having to extract it from the options in initialize), however, AFAIK, there will exactly 0 differences between a 'collection' view or a 'model' view or a 'collection+model' view. In other words, they aren't even tied to Models, they are tied to a DOM element and that's pretty much it!

Comment: Enders - your first point was why I was confused with all of this. Adding the model to the collection should have made it work, but I got errors until I added the view. That's why they are both in there. Thanks for responding. I wish I saw your message earlier - i hacked on this thing until it worked. Embarrassing, but it works ;/